# NHZT-W58 Sat Nav

Tags: audio, navigation, camera

Can someone please help me to show how to change language setting from Japanese to English on sat nav system model NHZT-W58.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you searched for the manual - that’s what we would do

Comment: In [this Q&A site](https://www.fixya.com/support/t9511956-set_language) the 5th answer down says "I went back into setting by scrolling along until a picto gram - with what appears to be a machine bolt is highlighted and then pressed SET - next the screen shows a bunch of chinese words (these are the different languages) then I scrolled down to the last one - until its highlighted, - this is the english one - press the set button on the side of the frame, this will bring you back to the english menu."

Comment: @WeatherVane +1. You should probably put that as an answer IMO.